# Embed youtube video in canvas using mediaelement.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, youtube, mediaelement.js

I'm trying to embed youtube video in canvas using [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) according to [this page](http://johndyer.name/html5-video-wrapper-for-youtube-and-vimeo-api-mediaelement-js/). However, video is not loading, the control player is all black. Can anybody give me some hints? Here is my code, mostly follow the page (added `html5=true` to ensure html5 player from youtube):

EDIT: checked the demos under [the github repo](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/). Youtube demo is the only one that doesn't work. Guess it's an issue in this lib. However, any workaround would still be appreciated. The reason I want to do this is to feed the youtube stream to a html5 canvas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>youtube in canvas</title>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="mediaelement-and-player.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mediaelementplayer.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <video width="640" height="360" id="player1" preload="none">
    <source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI&html5=true" />
  </video>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#player1').mediaelementplayer();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```